# How to get a Substring from a String after a specific word

Tags: php, substring

I'm looking to get a Substring from a String:
The best way to explain this is with following example:

```
$string = 'locations?city=London';
if (strpos($string,'city=') !== false) 
{
   // now here I need something to get London in a string
}
```

Comment: Start with [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
parse_str( parse_url( 'locations?city=London', PHP_URL_QUERY ), $params );

print_r( $params );

// outputs: Array ( [city] => London ) 

echo $params['city'];

// outputs London
```

Comment: yep, that's what I was looking for :)