# URI Segment with Question Mark

Tags: codeigniter, uri

For my Rest WebService I need some variations to put the city or Region or something else in it. So my URI should look like this:

```
/rest/rating/locations?city=London
```

Now I'm using following functions to get the last URI Segment:

```
$segcount = $this->uri->total_segments();
$lastseg = $this->uri->segment($segcount);
```

The Problem is here that everthing from the Question Mark gets cutted!
The variable which gets saved is just: locations

I've tried configure following in the config.php:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Is there any other possibility to save the whole segment with the question mark?

Comment: i'm confused, `$this->uri->total_segments()` only returns the **#** of segments. Don't you want this: `$this->uri->segment_array()`

Comment: @tim: His method is getting the *last* URL segment (for whatever reason).

Comment: yes I need the last segment, after that I will use `$city = substr($lastseg, strlen("locations?city="))`to get the city in a string

Comment: @milepile: You're working way too hard. To get the city, just use `$this->input->get('city')`. If you're not reading from the current request but an actual string, use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). Looks like [someone already gave you this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463507/how-to-get-a-substring-from-a-string-after-a-specific-word).

Comment: @Madmartigan ... thanks for your help, didn't know the function, that's what I was looking for. I'm reading it from the request.

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you have:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
```

`enable_query_strings` is actually something else entirely, an old feature that's not used much.

The URI class still won't help you here, you'll have to refer to the query string separately.

```
$segcount = $this->uri->total_segments();
$lastseg = $this->uri->segment($segcount);

// Either of these should work
$query_string = http_build_query($this->input->get());
$query_string = $this->input->server('QUERY_STRING');

$lastseg_with_query = $lastseg.'?'.$query_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your config file, make sure the following is set as `TRUE`:

```
$config['allow_get_array']= TRUE;
```

Comment: @milepile: Read more carefully, you did not say you set this - you said you used `enable_query_strings`. Two totally different things. I know it's confusing, I wish they would drop support for that feature. See the bottom of this page (and read carefully): http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html